# can a function of a diagonalizable matrix be non-diagonalizable?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have a diagonalizable matrix $M$
$$M=P D P^{-1}$$
with $D$ diagonal. The usual definition of a function of this matrix, $f(M)$, is
$$f(M)=P \text{diag}(f(D_{11}),f(D_{22}),\cdots,f(D_{nn})) P^{-1}$$
Could it be that $f(M)$ is *not* diagonalizable?

To me, it initially seems that the answer is obviousely no, the diagonalisation of $f(M)$ is right there, it's $P \text{diag}(f(D_{11}),f(D_{22}),\cdots,f(D_{nn})) P^{-1}$. But I remain uncertain. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: As you said, with that definition of $f(M)$ the statement is true by definition.

Comment: If you define it by some power series expansion then it can't. (why)

Comment: Why are you uncertain?

Comment: I cannot give much context. During a paper review, someone asserted that is is easy to find functions of diagonalizable matrices which are non-diagonalizable. It's probably a matter of differing definitions of "a function of a matrix".

Comment: I need be more specific on my comment, for power series expansions with scalar coefficients.

Comment: Did the author define functions in the usual way as you described in your question, or did he use some wild definition?  Like, $f(x):=\lfloor x\rfloor$ can kind of be extended to matrices like this $$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\right):=\begin{bmatrix}\lfloor a\rfloor &\lfloor b\rfloor\\\lfloor c\rfloor&\lfloor d\rfloor\end{bmatrix}\,.$$  In this case, a diagonalizable matrix can be mapped to a non-diagonalizable matrix.  For example, try $(a,b,c,d)=\left(\frac12,\frac12,1,\frac12\right)$.  This is a stupid example, I know, but I can't rule out strange definitions.

Answer (score 1):

A *function* is just an assignment of a value to every argument. This assignment doesn't need to be in form of an explicit expression, and even when it is, the assignment for a diagonalizable matrix doesn't have to be diagonalizable. For example, let for any diagonalizable matrix $d$ of arbitrary quadratic size,
$$f(d) := \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
This is *not* diagonalizable although $d$ is.

Comment: In this context, $f$ is a function from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$. This is standard operator theory jargon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus

Comment: And that page says that there isn't always an obvious way to extend a function to operators (like matrices) although often $f(z)$ can be written as a polynomial or a series, and then just replacing $z$ with the matrix in the polynomial or series is the most natural.