# Matrix functions which are not scalar coefficient power series expansions.

Tags: matrices, soft-question, power-series, diagonalization

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2868167/can-a-function-of-a-diagonalizable-matrix-be-non-diagonalizable), I started to wondering (firstly) if there exist any (useful / famous) matrix functions which are not defined as power series expansions with scalar coefficients, but rather matrix coefficients:

$$f({\bf A}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {\bf C_k A}^k, {\bf C_k,A}\in M^{n\times n}$$

I suppose that it would be more difficult to show that $\bf A$ diagonalizable $\Rightarrow f({\bf A})$ diagonalizable (in the general case) as it obviously is in the special case $\forall k: {\bf C_k}=c_k{\bf I}$ (scalar coefficients). Since identity commutes with all matrices.

(Is it even true? (secondly))

Comment: I kind of doubt that $A$ diagonalizable implies $f(A)$ diagonalizable unless there were additional constraints on the $C_k$

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Yes I also very much doubt it, but I am also not sure if many such functions make sense. Most matrix functions I have seen are power series expansions of normal one variable real valued functions which always have scalar coefficients.